# How to handle activities android

Tags: android, android-activity

I open an Activity B from Activity A and then from Activity B opening Activity C. 
Now on clicking back from Activity C, it should open activity B , if I press ok in Activity C it should go back to Activity A.

```
public class ActivityA extends ActionBarActivity  
{  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    ....
    }

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent,100);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)

    {

        return;

    }


    if(requestCode == 100)
    {
        String val=data.getStringExtra(“result_str”);
        ....

    }
}
}

public class ActivityB extends ActionBarActivity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    ....
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);

    startActivityForResult(intent,100);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

{

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if(resultCode != RESULT_OK)

    {

        return;

    }


    if(requestCode == 100)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.putExtra(“result_str”,data.getStringExtra(“result_str”));
        intent.putExtra("val",val);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
}
}

public class ActivityC extends ActionBarActivity
{
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
    ....
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    ....
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.putExtra(“result_str”,result)

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

    finish();
    }
 }
```

In this case, i could see two activities getting disappear. I don’t want to see both the activities finishing visually. How to implement it?

Comment: use intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Answer (score 1):

1. If you press back button in Acitivity c just finish Activity c it goes to activity B.
2. If you press ok button set ***FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP*** to intent and start activity a and finish Activity c. It finishes Activity c and Activity B and goes to activity A.

Comment: I can't start ActivityA newly from ActivityC as it depends on value from ActivitiyB. Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: If you start newly then remove flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Finish Activity a while starting Activity B or other. When start Acitivty A again from c just add params to intent and read that params in   Acitivty A.

Answer (score 0):

**Do Below code**

you want to start B from A then write below code in A activity in any click metho or event.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
```

Now you have to open C activity from B then use as use val above code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
```

Now Open B activity on C activity on Back and on Ok button time open A acivity.

Here code for open A acivity from C at ok button press.

```
     Intent i = new Intent(this, A.class);
     startActivity(i);
     finish();
```

and below code write in onBack button press from C activity and open B activity.

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

     Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
     startActivity(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now on clicking back from Activity C, it should open activity B

**In your AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
   android:name=".C"
   android:label="Activity C"
   android:parentActivityName=".B">

   <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value=".B"/>
 </activity>
```

> if I press ok in Activity C it should go back to Activity A

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityC.this,ActivityA.class);
    startActivity(intent);
   }
});
```